# UK group or tourist visa application

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, study

My brother was recently selected to attend 1-week academic course in the UK university after he participated in the local tournament for 14-16 years old students. The government and the UK university provides support and funding for students when applying for visa. He also decided to spend one week in the UK after finishing this academic course. I am currently studying in the UK, so my university letter and other supportive documents can be submitted with his application.  However, I believe when he applies for visa he will be considered as a member of one group, rather than individual, and in turn will receive a 7-day visa because government sponsors his visit, not the family. Will it be appropriate if he applies separately for tourist visa and what can he add to his application to be successful, apart from standard identification, financial documents, my personal documents and confirmation of the place where he will live in the UK?

Comment: Which ‘government’ and ‘UK university’ (there are many) are you referring to? Do the terms of the tournament/government sponsorship allow what you are proposing?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now until they clarify.